# Single Quotes or No quotes in file paths in Unix shells

Tags: file, unix, terminal, scripting, command

I am new to Unix systems and trying to learn some thing with help of terminal. I have following question in my mind. If we can write filepath without single quotes in terminal (for ex : mv path1 path2) then why we sometime use single quotes to specify paths. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a question of the operating system, but of the shell you use. You can actually chose what shell you want to use on a unixoid system if multiple are installed (which usually is the case).

In general the shell has to interpret the input you make. It has to decide how to handle the tokens of the input. What to consider as the "command" you want to execute, what as arguments. For the arguments it has to decide if the string is meant as a single argument or multiple arguments.

Without quotes (single or double quotes), whitespace characters are considered separators between words, words are typically considered separate arguments. So you can specify multiple arguments for a single command. If that is *not* desired then you can use quote characters to group multiple words separated by whitespace characters into a single argument, for example a folder name containing a space character. This works because now the shell knows that you want everything following the quote character to be considered as a single argument up to the next matching quote character (actually except escaped ones...).

Comment: If i want to move all pdf files,is it compulsory to use quotes?

Comment: Why should that be the case? You want to use a wildcard to target all files following a given name scheme, if that is what you mean by "all pdf files" (files do not have to have a ".pdf" file name extension to be pdf documents...). But whether you want to use quotes depends on whether you need them. So whether you need to specify whitespace characters inside the path's folder names of the base file name itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's used to escape spaces in file names, otherwise, a backslash is needed. For instance:

```
$ rm spaces\ in\ file\ name
$ rm 'spaces in file name'
```

If your file path does not have spaces, it's probably safe to omit the quotes.